# 0 How to integrate Payseal in ASPNET 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

```
SFAClient objSFAClient=new SFAClient("E:\\HostingSpaces\\nkumar\\rahim.rakih.cz\\wwwroot\\Config\\");

objPGResponse=objSFAClient.postSSL( objMPI, objMerchant, oBillToAddress, oShipToAddress,oPGreservData,oCustomer,oSession,oAirLine,oMerchanDise);
```

Result is getting like this

> Response Code:2Response message:Initialization of sfa.properties
>   failed

Can you please check this?

Comment: Check _what_? And what do the "0" and "1" mean in your title?

Answer (score 0):

go to testssl.aspx

SFAClient objSFAClient=new SFAClient("Give your exact path of the sfa.properties which is inside config file which is provided by icici.");

Note : Path should be \ double slashed eg: C:\Users\

Inside sfa.peoperties there is a parameter Key.Directory=Give path of the key file which is downloaded from Merchant Web Interface URL.

I am also doing the same payment gateway integration. If you have any queries kindly reply me.